# NameError: global name 'choice_text' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner to Django. The following code is from the tutorial on the Django official site:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

I'm doing the following in a python shell (I have imported everything necessary from before):

```
>>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> p.choice_set.all()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 80, in __repr__
    return repr(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 421, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "/home/sumrok/pydev/mysite/polls/models.py", line 19, in __unicode__
    return self.choice_text
NameError: global name 'choice_text' is not defined
```

Where have I gone wrong to with this?  Why am I receiving these errors, and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to restart your server, it is running stale bytecode.

The source code shown does not match the exception (there is *no* global name `choice_text` being accessed on that line, only an attribute `self.choice_text`). Tracebacks have to use the source code from disk when showing an exception, and if the source code has changed in the meantime the byte code and source code are out of sync and errors stop making sense.

Answer (score 2):

I only can imagine that you imported the whole stuff and then made changes on it.

The version in memory is still `return choice_text` and the `self.`, which you obviously added later, is not yet present.

The solution would be to `reload(your_module)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do this:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
     def __init__(self):
          self.poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
          self.choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
          self.votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     def __unicode__(self):
          return self.choice_text
```

It should work.